# Whats up with Titanfall being unable to fill game matches?

Tags: titanfall

Is it just me or is matchmaking in Titanfall completely broken? Wondering if my network settings or something could be giving me a hard time.

I end up in matches with only two–three players on each team. How hard can it be to find 12 players for a match? It does not matter if I leave and rejoin or how long I play.

Is there anything I can do? or is it all up to EA’s servers?

Comment: Game is dead, not many are playing it. That is why your matches are empty.

Comment: What platform are you playing on? What playlist? What region? Do you have dlc maps?

Comment: @TZHX, Windows. I have the season pass and I pick a playlist at random. I guess my region is Europe?

Comment: Watching other’s play on Twitch; they don’t seem to have trouble finding other players. The streams are live, but when I go on I never get a full match. That is why I suspect it could be network or something else on my side.

Comment: It sounds very likely that you have strict NAT. Try to google "strict nat" and see if you can determine if that is the problem. If it is then you'll also find lots of help solving the problem. Unfortunately there are cases where the NAT is because of your local ISP or other causes out of your control. It is definitely not EA's servers though, since other people can play just fine.